# How could Batya convert without a Jewish court?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, rashi, shemot-exodus

A follow up to ["how-did-batya-know-that-tevilah-is-part-of-conversion"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126484/how-did-batya-know-that-tevilah-is-part-of-conversion).

[Rashi in place (Sota 12b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.12b.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) proposes that by dipping in the Nile Batya converted (presumably to Judaism).

For Rashi, how would dipping in private, not in front of a Jewish court help Batya to convert?

Comment: This question is posed by the Maharitz Chiyus on Rashi Megilla 13A. He does not give an answer  https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14306&st=&pgnum=420

Comment: Presumably you know the easy answer, "this was before the Torah was given...."

Comment: Can't people technically convert without a court even now? But we just suspect them?

Comment: @Aaron we recommend people use a *recognized* court (affiliated with the RCA or Israeli Rabbinate or the like) to avoid suspicion in a way that did not exist before the 20th century. But a "court" (meaning a beit din, 3 unrelated adult shomer  shabbat Jewish men) has been required at least since the Babylonian exhile