# What is the earliest source mentioning dipping in the water as a means of conversion?

Tags: sources-mekorot, conversion-to-judaism

I was arguing with a Christian about the Jewish ancient tradition to dip in the water as a means of spiritual conversion, but I only had Talmudic sources (the [Gerim Tractate](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Gerim?tab=contents)).

What is the earliest source mentioning dipping in the water as a means of conversion?

Comment: Maseches gerim is post talmudic

Comment: @robev It would still be a *Talmudic* source, unlike Biblical, Mishnaic, or later.

Comment: What’s masechet gerim? Is that from the Yerushalmi or something?

Comment: @CuriousYid https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Gerim?tab=contents

Comment: Basya went down to the river to convert, according to some interpretations

Comment: @Chatzkel How did she convert even before the Torah was given? Was it a standby conversion, which she would have reaffirmed after Matan Torah?

Comment: @MarsSojourner that is indeed a good question. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126484/how-did-bisya-basya-know-that-tevilah-is-part-of-conversion. However, Rashi still understands that it was conversion somehow, which would be an explicit source of dipping as a means of conversion

Comment: @Chatzkel That would not be an *explicit* source. She is not mentioned converting in any way.

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in כריתות [ט ע"א](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.9a.9?lang=bi) writes

> הרצאת דמים דכתיב (שמות כד, ה) וישלח את נערי בני ישראל אלא טבילה מנלן דכתיב (שמות כד, ו) ויקח משה חצי הדם ויזרק על העם ואין הזאה בלא טבילה The Gemara continues: And granted as well, they entered the covenant through the sprinkling of blood, as it is written: “And he sent the young men of the children of Israel, and they sacrificed burnt offerings, and they sacrificed peace offerings” (Exodus 24:5). The Gemara asks: But from where do we derive that immersion in a ritual bath was also part of the process of entering the covenant? The Gemara answers: As it is written: “And Moses took half the blood…and sprinkled it on the people” (Exodus 24:6–8), and there is no sprinkling of sacrificial blood without immersion.

In short, the first source is the pasuk in משפטים [כ"ד פסוק](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.24.7?lang=bi&aliyot=0) ח

> וַיִּקַּ֤ח מֹשֶׁה֙ אֶת־הַדָּ֔ם וַיִּזְרֹ֖ק עַל־הָעָ֑ם וַיֹּ֗אמֶר הִנֵּ֤ה דַֽם־הַבְּרִית֙ אֲשֶׁ֨ר כָּרַ֤ת יְהֹוָה֙ עִמָּכֶ֔ם עַ֥ל כׇּל־הַדְּבָרִ֖ים הָאֵֽלֶּה׃
> Moses took the blood and dashed it on the people and said, “This is the blood of the covenant that יהוה now makes with you concerning all these commands.”

Comment: +1 for effort! This, however, would be a *hint*, not *mentioning*. The assertion "*no sprinkling of sacrificial blood without immersion*" is still unsupported.

Comment: I think he's looking for a source in the written Torah. I think the answer is the earliest source is oral